# Eclipse 2023 09 Header file not found but it is there

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have software that builds ok on the command line. I import this code into a C managed Eclipse project. I set the Paths and symbols include folder that contain header files.

The very first header is not found when I build all. #include "folder/header.h"

If I edit to: ../folder/header.h .. on the next build it finds it .. but does not find the next one.

Seems as if this gets me out of the build folder and into my "folder" which is directly under the project folder.

I don't want to edit all 2000 header files but rather do things correctly. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess F Eclipse then since the Eclipse forum wont even post my question and stackE is dead?  Ima go with Netbeans.